# How can I remove a Listener from a socket in Dart

Tags: sockets, flutter, listener

I am using a Socket for a project. I connected it to a listener using the following code:

```dart
widget.secureSocket.listen((message) => onMessageReceived(String.fromCharCodes(message)));
```

How can I remove/disconnect onMessageReceived(...) from the socket?

Thank you in advance

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listen()` method returns a `StreamSubscription`, which you can cancel later.

```
var sub = widget.secureSocket.listen(...);
```

To cancel it:

```
sub.cancel();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!